# remove html tags from a column in hive. thoughts pls

Tags: hive

I have a column in hive table that has data in such format -

col1   col2
att

- International calls:  **$5** per call

sprint

- International calls:  **$10** per call

I want the data to be displayed in such format -
International calls $5 per call
International calls $5 per call

basically removing all tags. thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [regexp_replace](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) function?

```
SELECT regexp_replace(text,"</?[^>]*>","") FROM table;
```

For instance:

```
hive> SELECT regexp_replace("< html >my text</html> <br>fd<br>","</?[^>]*>","");
OK
my text fd
```

Comment: nope. it is still not removing all the tags from the string

Comment: Please edit your question and give an example of such tags that do not work.